# Ruby on Rails variables, object attributes, and methods that use a : before or after them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is a general question I'm just hoping to gain a little clarity about RoR syntax on the placement of the colon.

I'm going through Michael Hartl's rails tutorial for a second time and I'm wondering if anyone would be kind enough to explain to me the difference between calling a method or variable with the : before or after the name?  For instance, the "email" attribute to the Users class is sometimes called with :email and other times with email:. I know ruby is pretty versatile so I guess my real question is, does the ruby interpreter read these as a reference to the same object/attribute/method or does the syntax of where the colon appears change the handling in some way? Is one way calling and the other is more of a reference and would the same convention be applicable to all objects?

And lastly I guess is this more of a RoR style or will I see it often as I venture deeper into ruby itself?

Thanks

Edit: Down-voted for asking a legitimate question to help clarify syntax usage and meanings and then thanking people for answering? Some people on here really need to get over themselves.

@AnthonyMichaelCook I hear what you're saying, but the question was very basic and didn't require code samples in order to be answered. Two people gave clear concise answers and 1 other commented on variable assignments. I thanked them for their responses and moved on, then two ppl came behind and voted after the fact; it just has a ring a petty to it. Simple questions that have straightforward answers hardly require some long drawn out question/explanation with multiple examples that just annoy the reader with redundant and/or unnecessary information. But in-part the comment about people needing to get over themselves, was derived not just from this being down-voted but also from responses I read to other questions on stackoverflow while searching for the answer myself. I came across more than a few posts where some responders were borderline disrespectful and gave condescending or even non-answers and just a wise-buck comment. I was a network admin years ago when I first came to this site and I just get the impression that maybe the community has changed a bit from what it was when I used to be a regular visitor/contributor.

Comment: You'd be better off to show a more concrete example.

Comment: Providing a link to the tutorial you're looking at would be nice, as well as clearly formatted code samples, would likely have prevented the downvotes. You can always go back and edit your question and people might remove the downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [:symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html)
>
> [{key: value}](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Hash.html)

When the colon is *before* the variable / object, it denotes a "symbol", meaning a piece of data to be placed there. The symbol can typically be used in the likes of calling an attribute (key) or in part of a hash: `@user.comment[:created_at]`

When the colon is *after* the variable / object, it means you're *setting* or *getting* some sort of value in a `key: value` pair. `{key: value}` pairs are used mostly in hashes, kind of like an array except you can call the specific keys. This is how the attributes of models are invoked in Rails. EG:

```
@user = {name: "joe", email: "joe@email.com"}
@user.name #-> "joe"
```

Comment: To add to the confusion - you can also write `@user = {:name=>"joe", :email=>"joe@email.com"}`

Comment: Sure but that's old Ruby syntax

Comment: @RichPeck Thanks for breaking that down for me, it totally makes sense now. I'd give you an up vote but I don't have the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these usages of the colon is a different part of plain Ruby syntax. They are both common in Rails programming, so it's great to get them each clear in your mind while reading Rails code.

When the colon comes first (eg, :email), that is a "[Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html)". It's a simple substitute for a string that is extremely memory efficient.

When the colon comes last (eg, email:), that is a part of a "[Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html)". This is a data structure that is like a plain list (or array), but each element has its own name (email: is setting the name for the value that comes after the colon in this usage).

Comment: Thanks, you and Rich helped me a bunch by explaining it.