# what is the difference in ":some_text" vs "some_text:" in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am quite new in ruby and rails and get confused in this stuff what is  :something  and what is something:

please help me out :<

Comment: You can find the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080736/ruby-on-rails-variables-object-attributes-and-methods-that-use-a-before-or-a) question.

Answer (score 2):

`:some_text` is a [`Symbol`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Symbol.html). Whereas `some_text:` only makes sense in the context of a hash.

These both hashes are equal:

```
{ :foo => 'bar' }   # "old" hash syntax
{ foo: 'bar' }      # simplified newer hash systax, generates a `:foo` hash keys too
```

The newer syntax has the advantage that it is a bit shorter, but it only works when that hash keys should be symbols. When you need other hash keys, for example integers, then you have to use the "older" syntax like this: `{ 1 => 'bar' }`

Comment: "`some_text:` only makes sense in the context of a hash." … or in a parameter list, or in an argument list. Also note that it is not always obvious when you are in the context of a hash: `[foo: 42] #=> [ { :foo => 42 } ]`